# Django filter logic

Tags: django

I am trying to filter based on a parent having assigned user_roles or not and cant quite work out how to achieve the below in the most efficient way.

What i need to do is, if the parent has no user_roles assigned then i want all parent objects (essentially ignore the filter). But if it has some user_roles I want to filter based the Child object user_role also being in the Parent user_roles.

```
class UserRole(models.Model):
   name = charfield()


class Parent(models.Model):
   ...
   user_roles = m2m(UserRole)
   ...

class Child(models.Model):
   user_role = FK(UserRole)
```

Something like:

```
filter = Q(Q(parent__user_roles=Child.user_role) | Q(Ignore if parent__user_roles==None))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had answered without realising in teh actual question. Seems to work as I need.

```
filter = Q(Q(parent__user_roles=Child.user_role) | Q(parent__user_roles=None))
```